# What is most important feature you miss from Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

What is the feature you are missing the most on Notepad++?

Comment: Should be community wiki

Comment: Should be closed as subjective/argumentative.  Try the [Notepad++ feature request list](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=95717&atid=612385) instead.

Comment: Have you tried it before suggesting it? It doesn't have any voting options.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to replace the Notepad in Windows from the Notepad++ installer.